# RHEL8 (CentOS8): compiling nagios-plugins error with perl

Tags: plugins, nagios

I'm trying to compile the nagios plugins in a RHEL8 box but it fails and reports an error message when running `tools/build_perl_modules`

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/perlmods'
../tools/build_perl_modules -d /usr/local/nagios/perl -em .
make[2]: ../tools/build_perl_modules: Command not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1462: all-local] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/perlmods'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1431: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/nagios-plugins-2.2.1'
make: *** [Makefile:1352: all] Error
```

I compiled these same nagios plugins in RHEL5, RHEL6 and RHEL7 some time ago with no problem.

The `tools/build_perl_modules` does EXIST:

```
# ls -l tools/build_perl_modules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9999 Jun 16 12:27 tools/build_perl_modules
```

In fact, when launched that perl program:

```
# ../tools/build_perl_modules -d /usr/local/nagios/perl -em .
-bash: ../tools/build_perl_modules: yes: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This message is because of the shebang line

```
#!yes
# SYNTAX:
```

which is very weird for me. And yet, it worked in previous RHEL releases!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

After installing **`perl-Module-Build`** the error message disappeared.

Comment: Then, what damn does the `configure` script check for? It should report that perl module is not found in the Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Please install  Nagios PL

dnf install nagios-plugins-all